# TypeError: img should be PIL Image. Got <class 'numpy.ndarray'> - PyTorch

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pytorch

I'm trying to prepare some image data for my neural to classify. As part of the image preprocessing step, I'm applying the HOG filter in my dataset class as such:

```
class GetHogData(Dataset):

  def __init__(self, df, root, transform = None):
    self.df = df
    self.root = root
    self.transform = transform

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.df)

  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    if torch.is_tensor(idx):
      idx = idx.tolist()

    img_path = os.path.join(self.root, self.df.iloc[idx, 0])
    # image = Image.open(img_path)
    image = cv2.imread(img_path)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    label = self.df.iloc[idx, 1]

    if self.transform:
      image = self.transform(image)

    hog_, hog_image = hog(
        image,
        orientations = 9,
        pixels_per_cell = (14,14),
        cells_per_block = (2,2),
        block_norm = "L1")
    
    image = np.transpose(image, (2, 0, 1))

    img_hog_lbl = {
        "image" : torch.tensor(image, dtype = torch.float32),
        "label" : torch.tensor(label, dtype = torch.long),
        "hog": torch.tensor(hog_, dtype = torch.float32)
    }
    return img_hog_lbl
```

After this, I define my train and validation transformation as such:

```
# Image mean and standard dev 

img_mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
img_std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]

train_trans = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(img_mean, img_std)
    ])
        
test_trans = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(img_mean, img_std)
    ])
```

and finally, I create the loaders as such:

```
train_img = GetHogData(df = train_lab, root = "/content/train", transform = train_trans)
test_img = GetHogData(df = test_lab ,root = "/content/test", transform = test_trans)
```

However, when I attempt to preview the training image with `test_img[1]`  I get the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-b9a9394eb1e0> in <module>()
----> 1 test_img[1]

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional_pil.py in resize(img, size, interpolation)
    207 def resize(img, size, interpolation=Image.BILINEAR):
    208     if not _is_pil_image(img):
--> 209         raise TypeError('img should be PIL Image. Got {}'.format(type(img)))
    210     if not (isinstance(size, int) or (isinstance(size, Sequence) and len(size) in (1, 2))):
    211         raise TypeError('Got inappropriate size arg: {}'.format(size))

TypeError: img should be PIL Image. Got <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I've tried to add `transforms.ToPILImage()` to my transforms by doing:

```
# Image mean and standard dev 

img_mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
img_std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]

train_trans = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToPILImage(),
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(img_mean, img_std)
    ])
        
test_trans = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToPILImage(),
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(img_mean, img_std)
    ])
```

but I got the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-135-b9a9394eb1e0> in <module>()
----> 1 test_img[1]

1 frames
<ipython-input-129-8551c2e76038> in __getitem__(self, idx)
     27         pixels_per_cell = (14,14),
     28         cells_per_block = (2,2),
---> 29         block_norm = "L1")
     30 
     31     image = np.transpose(image, (2, 0, 1))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/skimage/feature/_hog.py in hog(image, orientations, pixels_per_cell, cells_per_block, block_norm, visualize, transform_sqrt, feature_vector, multichannel)
    273     n_blocks_col = (n_cells_col - b_col) + 1
    274     normalized_blocks = np.zeros((n_blocks_row, n_blocks_col,
--> 275                                   b_row, b_col, orientations))
    276 
    277     for r in range(n_blocks_row):

ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

Does anybody have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Edit - New Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-b9a9394eb1e0> in <module>()
----> 1 test_img[1]

<ipython-input-151-8551c2e76038> in __getitem__(self, idx)
     27         pixels_per_cell = (14,14),
     28         cells_per_block = (2,2),
---> 29         block_norm = "L1")
     30 
     31     image = np.transpose(image, (2, 0, 1))

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: "I've tried to add `transforms.ToPILImage()` to my transforms but with my luck" We can only tell you what went wrong when you tried to do this, if you show us the exact way that you tried.

Comment: Hi @KarlKnechtel, I've updated the post to show what I got. Thanks

Comment: Okay, that shows the error when you "tried to add" that code. I still don't see the version of the code where that part is "added". So I still can't guess *how* you "tried to add" it.

Comment: My apologies, @KarlKnechtel - I have now included it, thanks again

Comment: The last edit datagen itself is correct, `skimage` requires the data to be ndarray but you give it a torch tensor thus that error

Comment: Hi @NatthaphonHongcharoen, thanks for the reply. Where does this happen in my code? Is it where I have def __getitem__ ? Thank you

Comment: @ZedZee See the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is as I wrote in the comment, skimage requires the data to be ndarray but you give it a torch tensor thus that error.

Try this

```
    train_trans = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToPILImage(),
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(img_mean, img_std),
        lambda x: np.rollaxis(x.numpy(), 0, 3)
    ])
```

## Edit

This is basically transform the output to ndarray and change channel axis.

But as you can see it's not the best way to fix things since you have to transform PIL image to tensor then transform tensor to ndarray and then transform ndarray back to tensor again.

The better way to do this is transform PIL image directly to ndarray and normalize that, for example.

### in getitem

```
    if self.transform:
      image = self.transform(image)

      # add these
      image = np.array(image)

      mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
      std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]

      x[..., 0] -= mean[0]
      x[..., 1] -= mean[1]
      x[..., 2] -= mean[2]
      x[..., 0] /= std[0]
      x[..., 1] /= std[1]
      x[..., 2] /= std[2]

    # these are your code
    hog_, hog_image = hog(
```

And in transform just use

```
    train_trans = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToPILImage(),
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    ])
```

## Edit2

Refer to [this line](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/main/skimage/feature/_hog.py#L301). You need to either add `visualize=True` in `hog()` or remove `, hog_image`. If you don't need `hog_image` then the latter is preferred.

```
    hog_, hog_image = hog(
        image, visualize=True,
```

```
hog_ = hog(
```

Comment: Hi @NatthaphonHongcharoen - thanks for the suggestion, I believe it worked however I'm now getting a new error



ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-b9a9394eb1e0> in <module>()
----> 1 test_img[1]

<ipython-input-151-8551c2e76038> in __getitem__(self, idx)
     27         pixels_per_cell = (14,14),
     28         cells_per_block = (2,2),
---> 29         block_norm = "L1")
     30 
     31     image = np.transpose(image, (2, 0, 1))

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Put that in the question, this is so hard to read

Comment: My apologies, I have added it @NatthaphonHongcharoen

Comment: @ZedZee Added the answer for that

Comment: Thank you very much, @NatthaphonHongcharoen - the issue was indeed the extra hog_image variable - thank again.